# Build a Web service for iOS

Tags: ios, web-services

I want to implement an iOS application where users participate in collecting information and automatically submit it online. I need advice on how to build the web service to accommodate for the application need. Can someone point out some resources on how to do this. I was told that Node JS would be an easy and quick way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you like PHP, Asp, Java etc..

I Suggest PHP, here is a [simple tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json)

Comment: I don't suggest PHP. Go the Java servlet route, much more extensible and when used with maven and heroku, you can have a server up and running in no time.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Java servlet sounds overkill on a beginner doesnt it?

Comment: While it may seem complex to a beginner, in the long run, they would be thankful. Java servlets are much more powerful than PHP scripts, especially for sharing code.

Comment: well do you advice servlets to a beginner? does it have an easy learning curve? what if he didnt even know java? will it still be easier from php to learn and implement?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Can you guide me to more information on how to use Java Servlet. Also, isn't Heroku, etc a paid service? especially if I need to support a large number of users

Comment: @alandalusi if you want a simple web API, then heroku is the way to go. You can create a web service for free with it. As far as using java servlets, take a look here: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/